# How to redirect to HTML page present one level above folder

Tags: javascript

I have this directory structure as shown

[image]

Inside the www folder as shown in the figure (www folder naming convention as per  phonegap requirement) there are two items

**customer folder**

**ORcapture.html**

From ORcapture.html  i am redirecting to a html page present under the customer folder  ths way

window.location = "customer/index.html?qruuid="+uuid;

My question is

From customer/index.html file how can i redirect back to ORcapture.html  ??

Please let me know how to redirect in this case ??

Answer (score 3):

You should use ../.

```
window.location = "../capture.html";
```

Comment: Its just a little help :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's always best to use absolute URLs, when possible. In your example, it would be:

```
window.location = "/customer/index.html";
```

and

```
window.location = "/ORcapture.html";
```

If you still want to use relative URLs, you can denote a parent directory using `../` (instead of `/`, which denotes a root dir) so the other one would be:

```
window.location = "../ORcapture.html";
```

but that would work *only with URLs which are one level deeper than that html file* (as opposed to the absolute URLs, which work from *everywhere*).

Comment: Absolute URLs start with `/` - yours are relative (;

Comment: @naeramarth7 Yeah, yeah, accidentally posted the answer in the middle of writing it. :) Thank you for pointing it out anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.location = "../ORcapture.html";
```